# Decode parameters in Java from ajax post with specials characters

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

I have a html page with a form, and the following code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'xxxxx',
   data: $('#contact-form').serialize(),
   type: 'post',
   cache: false,
   dataType: 'html',
   success: function (data) {....},
   error: contact.error
});
```

When i send a string by post from html page, for example, the string `áéíúó`, in Java I receive the string `Ã¡Ã©Ã­ÃºÃ³`.
What should I do to resolve this problem? Any help will be very greateful.

**(Date 20131401)
Solution:**
@TechSpellBound, thanks for your reply. Your solution motivated me to search another :D, well i found two more solutions that worked for me: 
1) In Java, using the following code:

```
String param =  new String(req.getParameter("param").getBytes(), "iso-8859-1");
```

2) Other solution was, in my Tomcat configure the file web.xml and put:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>encoding</param-name>
                <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
            </init-param>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>   

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then the file server.xml, put the property URIEncoding="UTF-8" in all connectors configured in.
Thank you again.

Comment: is your html page UTF-8, like it is supposed to? do you use utf-8 also on the server side? ajax calls are always utf-8.

Comment: We need to see more code to be able to help, for example the server-side code.

Comment: yes, in java I do something like this: <CODE> protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {...String name = req.getParameter("name");....} </CODE>. I also tried: with URLDecoder.decode(name, "UTF-8"), but still the same. This page is loaded dynamically with jquery (this page is a popup), how do I force the post to UTF-8 or the page?. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring one of the following in your HTML page :

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
...
</head>
```

**OR**

for cross browser compatibilty, add this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

at the top of the HTML page and

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8">
...
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your solution motivated me to search another :D, see in the top for more detailed explanation. Thank you again.